# Single gradle worker for unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle

Is it possible to let gradle know to use a single worker thread for all my unit tests? In console I could see many gradle workers are invoked in parallel to execute unit tests. In my case, that is not desired and I want Gradle to invoke the unit tests in a particular sequence. I have already created multiple test tasks and added `dependsOn` attribute so there is one level of sequencing already applied. However, for some test tasks, there are multiple unit tests and those are not sequenced. Gradle engages multiple workers here. Is there a way to make this also sequential?

Answer (score 5):

By default, a `Test` task will fork a single test JVM, which will run all of the task's tests sequentially. Test execution order can be controlled on the test framework level (e.g. by using JUnit suites), or by using multiple `Test` tasks rather than a single one.

When setting `Test#maxParallelForks` to a value higher than 1, a `Test` task will launch multiple test JVMs, and will spread test (class) execution across them. As before, each test JVM will run its tests in a single thread.